# Pop Up Permissions Window Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

How do I get the slick pop-up permissions window for Facebook apps? Currently the user has to go to the app page and it redirects them to log back into Facebook, which is not what I want AT ALL.

I'm currently using PHP to do the authentication - is this the correct language? Should I use Javascript or some other method? I just want to make a clean login/permissions granting, which after it is done directs to the application.

Comment: Try the facebook [dev manual](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pop-up permission window comes is used with the javascript SDK. Using OAuth, you can use the javascript to get the permissions and then share the information with the php SDK.

All you have to do is `cookie: true, oauth: true` in the `FB.init` in the js SDK.

> Used in conjunction with the JavaScript SDK, the PHP SDK can share
>   user sessions seamlessly across the client and server. If a user is
>   already logged in to their Facebook account, the JavaScript SDK will
>   pick up the login session and send it to the server via a cookie,
>   which the PHP SDK reads without any intervention on the developer's
>   part. Example here.

this is the url of the example
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/534/

Comment: Ok, I thought that might be the Javascript SDK as opposed to the PHP one. I'll make sure to use the Javascript one to log my user in, and then write my app in PHP (or whatever I see fit). Thanks!

Comment: I complemented the answer. I actually was looking for exactly the same thing like 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

You use an [OAuth dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) (which has a popup style you can select with a parameter) and include a `redirect_uri` parameter as the final destination for the user. Usually, that URI would be one on your server that logs the user in, then issues `window.close()` to close the popup.

Comment: Is this true even for the PHP SDK?

Comment: Yes, when the user comes back to the `redirect_uri` you can use the PHP SDK to get the user's access token based off the URL parameters Facebook passes it.